# Merge local Git commit with newer remote one, keeping both in history but preferring newer version

Tags: git, github

I have an online Git repo that I access its main branch from 2 laptops. In some situations, I might add small changes to the same file from both computers. When I commit and push from one laptop, sometimes the remote repo has a more updated commit (as I might use one of the devices offline while on train etc). I don't want to resolve conflicts manually.

I've read about auto merge (theirs vs ours)

```
git merge [branch] --strategy-option theirs
```

but here the preference is for the location.

I tried other strategies as `FETCH_HEAD` or `push -f` but both mean loosing data from one side, local or remote.

How can I make the preference for the date (most recent takes priority) while keeping all commits saved and not losing previous work?

Comment: Instead of trying to automate conflict resolution, why not adjust your workflow to avoid the conflict? Frequent push and pulls on the repo will help you to avoid dealing with conflicts in the first place.

Comment: `I don't want to resolve conflicts manually.` Who should else do it? I suspect your aversion against resolving conflicts comes from poor tooling experience when not using a proper 3-way merge tool. Start [using kdiff3 to resolve merge conflicts](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3). After beginning to use proper 3-way merge tools, encountering merge conflicts mostly goes from "Oh no!" to "meh".

Answer (score 2):

Having conflict often - especially when you're the author of both changes suggests that something is sub-optimal.

When you change different files or even different section of the same file git should be able to pull push with no conflicts so a persistent problem with conflicts is a bad sign.

I suggest that you:

1. Organise the code so that you don't need modify the same files often
2. Pull most recent changes before you go offline

---

Having said all this, you could try pull with rebase and see if this works for your situation: `git pull --rebase`.